# ExtJs reset on numberfield undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, reset

I'm trying to reset a numberfield so that it displays the empty text contents when a pop up is called again. In my current situation, I have a time spinner, that is for hours. If I set this to, say, 12, if I close the popup and reopen, it will default to 0, rather than the emptytext, which is set to 'hh'. Code is below.

```
xtype : 'numberfield',
                              itemId : 'HrItemId',
                              id : 'HrId',
                              width : 50,
                              emptyText : 'hh',
                              maxValue : 23,
                              minValue : 0,
                              maxLength : 2,
                              enforceMaxLength : true,
                              listeners : {
                                  change : function(textField, newValue, oldValue,eOpts) {
                                      if (newValue < 0 || newValue > 23) {
                                          checkMaxValue('vfcHoldHrItemId');
                                      } else {
                                          me.PopupWindow.queryById('continueButton').enable();
                                      }
                                  }
                              }

me.PopupWindow.queryById('HrItemId').setValue(0 ); // works, and shows in Firefox debugger as an object
me.PopupWindow.queryById('HrItemId').reset(); // shows in Firefox debugger as undefined
```

Comment: which extjs version is used?

Comment: It's 4.1.3 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that `me.PopupWindow.queryById('HrItemId')` really returns the expected number field. Number fields do have `reset` method since Ext 1 so the only way how it would "become" undefined is that you're not calling it on a numberfield.

There's another problem I see in the above code and it is that you use ids on components. That is a bad, or better say a deadly, practice as ids propagate down to html markup. Html ids must be unique on a page.

That means if you have a window with a form and fields and fields have ids, you mustn't have two instances of that window. If you do an unpredictable behavior ensues.

Comment: It definitely does return the expected field, as I can call the setValue function on it. Those two lines of code happen in the order displayed. I was reading as I saw something about reset() not working if the field has not been instantiated, so I was setting it before resetting it as a test. The set works fine. The reset does not.

The id thing is a design decision outside of my control unfortunately. :)

Comment: Well, if the field does not exist (not instantiated), no methods can work. But then setValue wouldn't work either. Any override? Or a bug  in Ext - but I don't believe it, reset is so core that it would break everything.

Comment: Nothing overridden. It's just a normal numberfield, nothing extra added. Definitely getting the right component as I threw in this code to check. var windows = me.vfcHoldPopupWindow.queryById('vfcHoldHrItemId');
            console.log(windows.getId());

Comment: Then prepare a showcase at https://fiddle.sencha.com - no other ideas w/o running the code.